# Finding how many bits it takes to represent a 2's complement using only bitwise functions

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, twos-complement, bitcount

We can assume an int is 32 bits in 2's compliment
The only Legal operators are: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

At this point i am using brute force

```
int a=0x01;
x=(x+1)>>1; //(have tried with just x instead of x+1 as well)
a = a+(!(!x));
```

...
with the last 2 statements repeated 32 times. This adds 1 to a everytime x is shifted one place and != 0 for all 32 bits

Using the test compiler it says my method fails on test case 0x7FFFFFFF (a 0 followed by 31 1's) and says this number requires 32 bits to represent. I dont see why this isnt 31 (which my method computes) Can anyone explain why? And what i need to change to account for this?

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html has all the answers you need in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [# of bits needed to represent a number x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105713/of-bits-needed-to-represent-a-number-x)

Answer (score 2):

`0x7FFFFFFF` does require 32 bits. It could be expressed as an *unsigned* integer in only 31 bits:

```
111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

but if we interpret that as a signed integer using two's complement, then the leading `1` would indicate that it's negative. So we have to prepend a leading `0`:

```
0 111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

which then makes it 32 bits.

As for what you need to change — your current program actually has undefined behavior. If `0x7FFFFFFF` (2<sup>31</sup>-1) is the maximum allowed integer value, then `0x7FFFFFFF + 1` cannot be computed. It is likely to result in -2<sup>32</sup>, but there's absolutely no guarantee: the standard allow compilers to do absolutely anything in this case, and real-world compilers do in fact perform optimizations that can happen to give shocking results when you violate this requirement. Similarly, there's no specific guarantee what `... >> 1` will mean if `...` is negative, though in this case compilers are required, at least, to choose a specific behavior and document it. (Most compilers choose to produce another negative number by copying the leftmost `1` bit, but there's no guarantee of that.)

So really the only sure fix is either:

- to rewrite your code as a whole, using an algorithm that doesn't have these problems; or
- to specifically check for the case that `x` is `0x7FFFFFFF` (returning a hardcoded `32`) and the case that `x` is negative (replacing it with `~x`, i.e. `-(x+1)`, and proceeding as usual).

Comment: There's no finite number of options compilers have to choose between; it's purely implementation-defined. For example the implementation could define that `x>>1` returns 32 bits from a hardware entropy source whenever `x` is negative. :-)

Comment: @R.: Whoops, you're right. What's more, this operation is exactly what standard gives as its example of implementation-defined behavior. I'll fix the answer; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code to check whether a signed integer *x* can be fitted into *n* bits. The function returns 1 when it does and 0 otherwise.

```
// http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~wms128/bits.c
int check_bits_fit_in_2s_complement(signed int x, unsigned int n) {
  int mask = x >> 31;

  return !(((~x & mask) + (x & ~mask))>> (n + ~0));
}
```